# I'm getting a call function error in vba?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have some functions in a worksheet excel objects that I want to excess from one of my forms. The error is "Object required" Any idea what I need?

```
Microsoft Excel Object:
    Public sub doThisFunction()
        msgbox("hello")
    End Sub

Forms:
    Call Sheets("Sheet1").doThisFunction
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Sheets` global collection is really referring to the the *active workbook*. Avoid implicit references!

Worksheets have a `(name)` property. If you didn't change it, then the object referred to by `Sheets("Sheet1")` can be accessed directly with the `Sheet1` identifier - assuming that's the case, this would work:

```
Sheet1.doThisFunction
```

Also note, the `ThisWorkbook.Sheets` collection contains chart sheets and worksheets. You *typically* would look for your sheet in the `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets` collection.

---

This line is also a problem:

```
MsgBox("hello")
```

You're using a function as if it were a procedure; when you're not interested in a return value, drop the parentheses:

```
MsgBox "hello"
```

When you're calling a function, you need them:

```
result = MsgBox("works?", vbYesNo)
```

By wrapping procedure arguments in parentheses, you're force-passing arguments `ByVal`, by forcing VBA to evaluate the *value* of what you're giving it.

For example:

```
Sub DoSomething(ByRef foo As Object)
    'foo is passed by reference
End Sub

Sub Foobar()
    DoSomething (ThisWorkbook) 'ThisWorkbook is force-passed by value
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`Call` is a deprecated, and redundant statement, you can just remove the `Call` keyword...

If your msgbox call isn't returning a value, then you can omit the brackets.

And to be sure you're working with the right sheet, try using the sheet's codename, which I'm asuming you have as `Sheet1` but you'll need to adjust the code,  if you've called it something else.

```
Microsoft Excel Object:
'This needs to be in Sheet1
    Public sub doThisFunction()
        msgbox "hello"
    End Sub

Forms:
    'This line needs to be in a `Sub` or `Function` block...
    Sheet1.doThisFunction
```

Comment: not working. I tried same thing.

Comment: have edited my answer